# Library for multiple consumer oAuth?

Tags: php, oauth

Does anyone know a good and/or easy to use PHP library/class/whatever-it's-called for being able to do oAuth against a large amount of providers (Facebook, AIM/AOL, MSN, all the 'big boys', etc)? All it needs to handle is essentially authentication, there won't be any permissions or anything - it just needs to be able to pull a login-verified username and a realname (optional).

Comment: I use [Janrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage) on my site.  It's easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Google recently released their [Google Identity Toolkit](http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/), that handles several auth providers, it maybe come in handy. There's [a PHP sample](http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/phpsample.html).